# Read or Write a compound datatype with h5py in python

Tags: hdf5, h5py

I want to use hdf5 file among some C++, matlab, and python code.
My h5 file works well in C++ and matlab, but cannot be read with h5py.

Is data types like H5T_STD_B64LE not well supported by h5py?
Thanks!

```
In [2]: f = h5py.File('art.mips.log.h5', 'r')

In [3]: f.keys()
Out[3]: [u'mem']

In [4]: f['mem']
Out[4]: <repr(<h5py._hl.dataset.Dataset at 0x29f70d0>) failed: TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists>
```

The hdf5 file format is as follows:

```
$ h5dump -H art.mips.log.h5  
HDF5 "art.mips.log.h5" { GROUP "/" {    DATASET "mem" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
         H5T_STD_B64LE "clock";
         H5T_STD_B32LE "addr";
         H5T_STD_B32LE "operation";
         H5T_ARRAY { [16] H5T_STD_B32LE } "data";
      }
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 68614468 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
      ATTRIBUTE "CLASS" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 6;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_0_NAME" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 6;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_1_NAME" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 5;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_2_NAME" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 10;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "FIELD_3_NAME" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 5;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "TITLE" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 4;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "VERSION" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STRING {
            STRSIZE 4;
            STRPAD H5T_STR_NULLTERM;
            CSET H5T_CSET_ASCII;
            CTYPE H5T_C_S1;
         }
         DATASPACE  SCALAR
      }
   }
}
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to discuss this if you provided a sample .h5 file (or at least included the config file for h5import to make it easy to have a sample dataset to experiment with; see https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/cmdtoolcvrt.html#h5import).

Comment: @Phil This is a sample file with everything [one drive link](http://1drv.ms/1gtnfiB) . Actually I pasted the same question in [h5py mail list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h5py/qBkiLEO40aY), and andrew suggests me do the type casting. I have not tried it, and I also wonder how I can write the h5 file with python in the same format, so other source codes can read it out without any code modifications.

Comment: Your question is clear, but I do not know an answer. I tried using astype as Andrew suggested on the mailing list, and got "IOError: Can't read data (No appropriate function for conversion path)". If you are able to change the writer, I suggest you pack the data into uint8 values rather than bits.

Comment: @Phil, actually this is what I am doing now, however, it requires changes on several different type of source code. I should not use "H5T_NATIVE_B*" type when the file is generated in C code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

h5py does not support bitfields, as stated in https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/109

I had a quick look at the low-level interface within h5py to see if there was a way to get the raw data out but it looks like the underlying `id` object needs to support a read() method.

```
>>> mem_id = h5py.h5o.get_info(f.id, 'mem')
>>> mem_id.read
...
AttributeError: 'h5py.h5o.ObjInfo' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: That's right, so far there is no good solution for this. I will just modify the writer to avoid this issue.