# How to fix "No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists" error in python

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I am reading a .h5 file with h5py module. What i am trying to achieve here is print all the groups and all the datasets within a group without knowing the content structure of the file. 
 I am using [visititems](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html#Group.visititems) function to iterate over all the nodes of the file.

My code works fine at first until it gives an error:

> TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists

I am new to h5py module so can anyone tell me why is this happening? This code runs fine for starting iterations of the loop but later some datasets/nodes of this file cause this error.
As far as i can understand is that some items(datasets or groups) from this .hf file are not being read correctly.

Link to this .h5 file i am using is : 
https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/wk7SN1qt2O7jbrl

This is my code:

```
AWAKE_csv = open('AWAKE_csv.csv', mode='w') 
AWAKE_writer = csv.writer(AWAKE_csv, delimiter=',')
AWAKE_writer.writerow(["GROUP", "DATASET", "SIZE", "SHAPE", "TYPE"])

def visitor_func(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
        print('Dataset: ' + name)

        out = node.dtype

        AWAKE_writer.writerow([' ', name, node.size, node.shape, out])
    else:
        print('Group: ' + name)
         # node is a group
        AWAKE_writer.writerow([name])


with h5py.File(glob.glob("*.h5")[0],'r') as f:
    f.visititems(visitor_func)
```

The line in my code which throws this error is:

```
out = node.dtype
```

Comment: I am using python 3.6.3 on Anaconda 5.0.1.

Comment: for time being you can ignore csv read and write.

Comment: A wed search on this `type`, indicates that it occurs in files created by `pytables`.  https://github.com/blaze/blaze/issues/847, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31303473/read-or-write-a-compound-datatype-with-h5py-in-python, https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/6473

Answer (score 1):

With this visit function, I can get information on all the datasets that raise this `node.dtype` error:

```
def foo1(name,node):
    #print(name)
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
        try:
            node.dtype
        except TypeError as err:
            print(name)
            print(node.size, node.shape)
            print(err)
```

I get a couple of screens worth, with a typical display like:

```
0 (0,)
No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists
AwakeEventData/GD_BPM.AWAKE.TRIUMF/AcquisitionSPS/posOK
1 (1,)
No NumPy equivalent for TypeBitfieldID exists
AwakeEventData/GD_BPM.AWAKE.TRIUMF/GlobalAcquisition/posOK
```

So if your goal is just to visit everything, and display the information that you can, add a `try/except` like this to your visit function.

The `h5dump` display for one of those datasets is:

```
2215:~/mypy$ h5dump -d /AwakeEventData/GD_BPM.AWAKE.TRIUMF/AcquisitionSPS/posOK ../Downloads/1541962108935000000_167_838.h5
HDF5 "../Downloads/1541962108935000000_167_838.h5" {
DATASET "/AwakeEventData/GD_BPM.AWAKE.TRIUMF/AcquisitionSPS/posOK" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_STD_B64LE
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
   DATA {
   (0): 80:17:00:00:00:00:00:00
   }
   ATTRIBUTE "bitFieldSize" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
      DATASPACE  SCALAR
      DATA {
      (0): 14
      }
   }
}
}
```

Adding `print(list(node.attrs.values()))` displays that `bitFieldSize` attribute.

There are other, non-python viewers.  I don't know if `pytables` or `pandas` could read this file or not.

Comment: yeah i knew that there are several datasets in this file that throw this error. And it was nice to use try/except. But can't we remove this error altogether? I mean the dataset do exist right? i want to read its contents into a numpy array but this error makes it impossible. or is there a way?

Comment: Anyways this was helpful too.

Comment: Actually i want to print the datatype specifically. If i tweak this try/except code just a little bit:


print(node.size, node.shape, node.dtype)


it again throws same typebitfield error. Obviously it will throw the error because it was already run in try block. so is there a way to get this special datatype of these datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this file is an interesting curiosity. **`HDFView`** has no trouble opening or viewing the data (even the troublesome ones). I wrote a little `pytables` code to walk the group hierarchy and report the leaf names. It issues this warning for several datasets:

```
DataTypeWarning: Unsupported type for attribute 'exception' in node 'BinningSetting'. Offending HDF5 class: 8
```

When I look at these datasets in `HDFView`, they show

```
Name: exception
Type: 8-bit enun (FALSE=0, TRUE=1)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about `HDF5` or `pytables` to explain what's going on. It's interesting that some of these datasets are different from those mentioned by @hpaulj.

Here's my code (warning: it creates a mountain of output):

```
import tables as tb

h5f = tb.open_file('1541962108935000000_167_838.h5',mode='r')
for grp in h5f.walk_groups('/') : 
    grp_leaves = grp._v_leaves
    if len(grp_leaves) > 0 :
        print ('Group: ', grp)
        for grp_leaf in grp_leaves :
            print ('\tLeaf:', grp_leaf)
```

The first few offending groups are:

```
Group:  /AwakeEventData/XUCL-SPECTRO/BinningSetting
Group:  /AwakeEventData/XUCL-SPECTRO/CameraSettings
Group:  /AwakeEventData/XMPP-STREAK/StreakImage
Group:  /AwakeEventData/TT43.BPM.430308/Acquisition    
Group:  /AwakeEventData/TT41.BTV.412426/Image
```

Does that help?

Comment: I saw the `enum` types when browsing the file.  `h5py` handles those a simple integers, http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/special.html#enumerated-types