# "TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeTimeID" when trying to access dataset from .h5 file

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I received a .h5 file from a colleague and I was trying to read the contents of it using the h5py library in python.

The dataset within the .h5 file throws the following error when I try to read the contents of the dataset using the command `dset[...] or dset[()]`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-bfb825264756> in <module>
----> 1 dset_test_new[...]

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

c:\users\raman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py in __getitem__(self, args, new_dtype)
    699 
    700         if new_dtype is None:
--> 701             new_dtype = self.dtype
    702         mtype = h5t.py_create(new_dtype)
    703 

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

c:\users\raman\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\dataset.py in dtype(self)
    454     def dtype(self):
    455         """Numpy dtype representing the datatype"""
--> 456         return self.id.dtype
    457 
    458     @property

h5py\h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.DatasetID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.TypeID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.TypeID.dtype.__get__()

h5py\h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.TypeCompoundID.py_dtype()

h5py\h5t.pyx in h5py.h5t.TypeID.py_dtype()

TypeError: No NumPy equivalent for TypeTimeID exists
```

where dset (expressed as "dset_test_new" in the error message) is a compound dataset of shape (2184,)

Now, I searched for a solution and I found this thread:
https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/360

I understand from the error message and the associated thread that this is a data type issue; but has this been resolved since 2014, when the Git thread was last active? Or am I to understand that HDF has moved away from this since then?

Is this just a case of an old .h5 file/data type which one can only resolve by re-creating .h5 file to the standards of the latest versions of HDF5 or is there a workaround by which you can convert this to something readable by python?

Comment: A more recent SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55480704/how-to-fix-no-numpy-equivalent-for-typebitfieldid-exists-error-in-python

Comment: Thanks for linking this SO as well; I did see this, I didn't attach it as it still leaves me none the wiser on the resolution of the particular attribute and data type issue. In fact, if anything, it just seems to add to the problem... now you have two data types that are not having no Numpy/python equivalent.  


But, unlike the other SO, I only have one dataset and one particular attribute that is causing this problem..

Comment: Was the .h5 file created on a Linux/Unix system? The comments in the attached h5py Github issue state that H5T_TIME(TypeTimeID) is not supported by h5py because it is unsupported by HDF5 (as of 2014). The github links to The HDF Group docs don't work (404 error). I found this regarding time in the documentation: [HDF5 Datatypes](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/11_Datatypes.html). Section 5.6 Time states: _"Currently, only Unix "time" and "timeval" structs are supported. "_

Comment: If you know which dataset has the H5T_TIME (and you don't need to read it), you might be able to program around it by creating a h5py dataset object (not a NumPy array), then accessing the data using the field name(s). Something like: `dset=h5file['dset name']  ; field_arr = dset['field name']`

Comment: 100% agreed on what you wrote about H5T_TIME being not supported by h5py and HDF5. I gleaned as much from the github discussion on h5py. The issue is that this .h5 was handed over to me with little info on the metadata, when this file was made and the structure of the groups and datasets. I found out most of the info from the attributes of the dataset itself. As for the fieldname solution, you proposed, I had already tried it, it didn't work.I think this is because the .h5 dataset is a compound dataset. I will contact the creator of the .h5 file and ask them, I guess. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Interesting. Your post said you read the data into an array; something like `arr=h5file['dset name'][...] or [()]`.  I thought you could avoid the dtype issue if you dropped the indices and created a h5py object instead with `dset=h5file['dset name']`  (no indices). Apparently not. One more thought: have you tried to read with PyTables (aka tables)? You might run into the same issue, but it would be worth a quick test.

Comment: Thank you.. that did the trick.. :) Thank you for suggesting trying with tables.. That problem vanished with tables, I will have to do some digging as to understand why. But, regardless, Tables successfully converted it into a Time32Col. I can see that there is some issue with this attribute however, as it still registers as having shape of () with values in them, while all other attributes have a given shape of (49,). Can you make this an answer please?? I would like to upvote it.. :)